# Can I create an aligned table with an if statement in python?

Tags: python, csv, alignment, spacing, tabular

I have data from a CSV file that tells whether or not a basketball player is obese.

I need to make a perfectly aligned table from this data; I have all the information to tell whether or not a player is obese. However, I have an "if" statement that prints out the values of each obese player and I need to make this print out in neat, aligned rows.

I have:

```
obese_count = 0
total_count = 0


print (" " * 5, "First Name", " " * 2, "Last Name", " " * 2, "Height"," " * 2,"Weight"," " * 2, "BMI") # header
print ("- " * 20)
for player in players:
    if has_data(player):
        if is_obese(player):
            print (" " * 5, player["firstname"]," " * 5, player["lastname"]," " * 9, player["h_feet"]," " * 9,player["h_inches"]," " * 5, player["weight"])
            obese_count += 1
        total_count += 1
```

which is returning a very sloppy table:

```
      First Name    Last Name    Height    Weight    BMI
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
      Carlos       Boozer           6           9       280
      Elton       Brand           6           8       275
      Glen       Davis           6           9       289
      Thomas       Hamilton           7           2       330
      James       Lang           6           10       305
      Jason       Maxiell           6           7       280
      Oliver       Miller           6           9       280
      Craig       Smith           6           7       272
      Robert       Traylor           6           8       284
      Jahidi       White           6           9       290
```

I was wondering if there is any way I could tidy this up, so that I can have a neat and aligned table or at least aligned rows that aren't spaced out differently.

Comment: [Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: As shown in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) documentation you can use `width` to define how wide each field is coupled with one of the `align` characters (`"<"` | `">"` | `"="` | `"^"`) to get it looking nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) is your friend.

For instance,

```
print '{:<10} {:<10} {:>2}\' {:>2}" {:>6}'.format(player["firstname"], player["lastname"], player["h_feet"], player["h_inches"], player["weight"])
```

This should return something like this:

```
Carlos     Boozer      6'  9"    280
Elton      Brand       6'  8"    275
Glen       Davis       6'  9"    289
```

As an aside: it looks like your table has a header for BMI, but there's not a corresponding field in your player dictionary.

Comment: Thanks I just added that in there; I didn't even notice. But I am getting an error when I try your suggestion: `TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what's causing this error, but it's something to do with the type of data you're passing to `.format()`. I'd guess it's the numbers, so I'd wrap `player("h_feet")` in `str()` to get: `str(player("h_feet"))`. Do the same for h_inches, weight, and BMI, and see if that works.

Comment: FWIW, I made the numbers strings when writing the code for the example. `players = [{'firstname':'Carlos','lastname':'Boozer','h_feet':'6','h_inches':'9','weight':'280'}, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) explains it very well.

```
>>> for x in range(1,11):
...     print '{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
...
1   1    1
2   4    8
3   9   27
4  16   64
5  25  125
6  36  216
7  49  343
8  64  512
9  81  729
10 100 1000
```